# Data transfer in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following requirement in SQL Server 2008 R2, trying to implement in a stored procedure

1. source table `T` with 100000 records, needs to be insert into destination table `T1`. A Job will be scheduled for this and it will be run 24x7 every hour (both tables are on the same server but in different schema)
2. During data transfer if the process fails because of source data issue for a specific record then process should update as this record has data issue in source table `T` as (data issue) and before that whatever the records inserted into destination table `T1` should have to commit and also update the source table as (Success). So that in next run process will avoid those records and pick the new records to from source `T` to transfer into `T1`.
3. Performance is the main factor as destination DB server is extremely busy and my process should not have to overload the database.

Can you please share any solution to this requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried selecting `T` into a temp table prior to moving them to `T1`? That way there wouldn't be any changes happening to your temp table data while you are trying to transfer.  You could also look into replication

Comment: also, are you wanting to do a full refresh of T1 every time, or are you looking for incremental changes only?

Comment: Could you specify what could be the "data issues in source table"? Are you performing a content validation on the data in T?